# Issue in loop getting the value

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I am having an issue in getting the data in the below loop ,even though the size is not zero i am getting null in the sysout 'data is'.What is wrong there ?

```
List<Long> dd = domainItemMapper.getIsSearchable(34372);
    System.out.println("the test is-" + dd.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < dd.size(); i++) {
        Long isSearch = dd.get(i);
        System.out.println("data is"+dd.get(i));
        if (isSearch.equals(0)) {
            isSearchValue = false;
        } else
            isSearchValue = true;
    }
```

The call to database is a mybatis call as below
interface

```
List<Long> getIsSearchable(@Param("parentFieldId") long parentFieldId);
```

impl

```
<mapper namespace="com.ge.dbt.common.persistence.IFormValidatorMapper">

        <select id="getIsSearchable" statementType="CALLABLE"
        resultType="Long">
        select is_searchable from t_field where parent_field_id=#{parentFieldId}
    </select>

</mapper>
```

Comment: A list with `null` records.

Comment: please provide some code of `domainItemMapper.getIsSearchable(34372)`

Comment: `List<Long>` is allowed to contain `null` elements. Apparently `getIsSearchable` returns such a list.

Comment: Code is edited for getIsSearchable

Comment: A table with `NULL` in `is_searchable` column.

Comment: The data has null,0 and 1 data.I want to return data only for 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your whole code can be converted in to two lines.

```
if(dd!= null && !dd.isEmpty())
 return dd.contains(0);//Contains Guard you in such cases because equals check
                       //happen on passed element ie *0*
```

Default value of `Long` in java is `null`. So you will need additional check for `null` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your `isSearch.equals` check in a `null` check

```
if(isSearch != null)
{
    if (isSearch.equals(0)) 
    {             
        isSearchValue = false;         
    } 
    else             
    {
       isSearchValue = true;
    }
}
```

However it'll be better to modify code for `domainItemMapper.getIsSearchable(34372);` method so that it doesn't fill the list with `null` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be your list contains `null` literals. And `List` Supports null as a value.

Answer (score 0):

based on your this comment

> The data has null,0 and 1 data.I want to return data only for 0 and 1.

You need to fix your query like this

```
 select is_searchable from t_field where parent_field_id=#{parentFieldId} and is_searchable is not NULL;
```